# Android - Setting Camera Resolution to 320 * 240 For Video recording programmatically using Intent

Tags: android

In Android, want to set the Camera Resolution to 320 * 240  programmatically including 30 seconds recording  only . Please suggest me some Logic .Remember that I want to perform all this by using Intent only i.e I am launching Video Camera using intent . So I required the solution to minimize the camera resolution programmatically using intents only.

Answer (score 3):

> So i required the solution to minimize the camera resolution programmatically using intents only.

You cannot set the camera resolution when invoking a third-party camera app for taking pictures or recording videos. Third-party camera apps are written by actual programmers, and those programmers can do what they want.

If you are [using `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE), you are welcome to include extras, [like `EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY), to *request* certain characteristics. But camera apps are welcome to ignore those extras (and some do), and there is no extra to force a particular resolution.

You are also welcome to implement your own video recording using `MediaRecorder`, skipping the third-party apps. Here, you can control the resolution... but only within the roster of resolutions supported by the device. There is no requirement that every Android device support recording any particular resolution, such as 320x240.